# R / JAVA / JGR How does this work?

Tags: java, r

I'm trying to do some work between java and r (using some of the cross-correlation tools and other stats functions) and am trying to use the `JGR` package.  I've spend a decent amount of time looking at the documentation and am having some difficulty figuring out how this JGR package works and even what its purpose is.  A few questions:

1) Where do I actually write the code?  In RGUI, in Eclipse, in some other console I have yet to experience?

I start by starting JGR:

```
> JGR()


Copy the following into WordPad and save as "jgrLaunch.bat"

set R_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-214~1.0
set R_LIBS=C:\Users\~\Documents\R\win-library\2.14
set R_LIBS_USER=C:\Users\~\Documents\R\win-library\2.14;C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\library
jgr-1_62.exe --rhome=C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-214~1.0 --libpath=C:\Users\~\Documents\R\win-library\2.14

Starting JGR ...
>
```

When I drop examples from the reference manual into R I get the following:

```
> jgr.addMenu("Workspace")
jgr.addMenu() cannot be used outside JGR.
> jgr.addMenuItem("Workspace","Browse","ls()")
jgr.addMenuItem() cannot be used outside JGR.
> jgr.addMenuSeparator("Workspace")
jgr.addMenuSeparator() cannot be used outside JGR.
> jgr.addMenuItem("Workspace","Browse (pos=2)","ls(pos=2)")
jgr.addMenuItem() cannot be used outside JGR.
> menus <- jgr.getMenuNames()
jgr.getMenuNames() cannot be used outside JGR.
> index <- which(menus=="Packages & Data")
> if(length(index)==0) index <- 1
> jgr.insertMenu("User menu",index)
jgr.insertMenu() cannot be used outside JGR.
> jgr.addMenuItem("User menu","A good place for user generated menus is","print(’before Packages & Data’)")
jgr.addMenuItem() cannot be used outside JGR.
```

But when I put it into eclipse there are things like `<-` that seem out of place.

2) Does anyone have any actual code?  I usually can figure this stuff out with a few code examples but haven't been able to track any down.

3) Any suggestions for a way that might be better/easier (ie different packages or setups)?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've never used this program before, but it looks like it's a *GUI*, or *Graphical User Interface*. That means you don't launch `R`, you launch whatever program came with JGR **instead**. When you are within that environment, you'll be able to use the `jgr` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JGR is *Java GUI for R* and you run it by double-clicking on the JGR icon -- which you download from http://rforge.net/JGR/web-files/jgr-1_62-x64.exe (64-bit) or http://rforge.net/JGR/web-files/jgr-1_62.exe (32-bit). What you loaded in R is merely the supporting R package and you ran it in Rgui, not in JGR (hence the errors).

JGR itself uses JRI (Java/R Interface) from [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) to load R into the Java process. If you are interested in using R from Java you can do the same. The API is documented in http://rforge.net/Rserve/doc/

You can use exactly the same API on the Java side with [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) which uses a client/server model of communication.

You can have a look at the [stats-rosuda-devel](http://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) mailing list which is a place to discuss JGR, rJava, JRI, Rserve etc.

Answer (score 1):

3) The easiest (fastest in terms of development) is probably [RCaller 2.0](http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/downloads/list)

It's a little bit slow because Java has to make an external call and it passes all the data through xml. You can find a useful blog [here](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php) and [here](http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2011/09/embedding-r-in-java-applications-using.html)

Other alternatives are that I haven't experimented with are:

1. [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/)
2. [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/)
3. [Renjin](http://stdioe.blogspot.com/2011/09/embedding-r-in-java-applications-using.html) in development...